# Sequelize Where Associated Model is Null

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 3 models: `Post`, `Photo`, and `Audio`.

A post can have a photo or an audio clip (or neither):

```
models.Post.hasOne(models.Photo, { as: 'photo' });
models.Post.hasOne(models.Audio, { as: 'audio' });
```

I'm trying to select those which have neither - i.e. are just a text post. I've been digging around, and I arrived at (sourcing information from [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3095)):

```
db.Post.findAll({
    where: {
        '$photo.id$': { $eq: null },
        '$audio.id$': { $eq: null }
    },
    order: [
        ['createdAt', 'DESC']
    ],
    include: [{... "photo" and "audio" - both with required: true}],
}).then((posts) => {
    ...
});
```

however, that doesn't seem to work (I don't think I fully understand how the related models are referenced). In addition, the resulting query uses `INNER JOINS` instead of `LEFT JOINS` so when it tries to join `Posts` and `Photos`/`Audios`, it produces an empty result instead of a result with all the values of `Post` and empty columns for `Photo` and `Audio`.

The produced query is:

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM "Posts" AS "Post"
    INNER JOIN "Photos" AS "photo"
        ON "Post"."id" = "photo"."postId"
    INNER JOIN "Audios" AS "audio"
        ON "Post"."id" = "audio"."postId"
    WHERE 
        "photo"."id" IS NULL AND
        "audio"."id" IS NULL
) AS ...
```

The query

```
SELECT *
FROM "Posts" AS "Post"
LEFT JOIN "Photos" AS "photo"
    ON "Post"."id" = "photo"."postId"
LEFT JOIN "Audios" AS "audio"
    ON "Post"."id" = "audio"."postId"
WHERE 
    "photo"."id" IS NULL AND
    "audio"."id" IS NULL
```

produces the result set I'm looking for. I think my issue is the `include: [{ ... required: true }, ...]` flag for each included model - but I'm not sure how to include it *for querying* but not *require* it for the result collection.

In my dream world, the sequelize query would look like

`db.Post.findAll({ where: { photo: { $eq: null }, audio: ... } })`

Answer (score 9):

Use `required: false` to generate left outer joins.

```js
const lonelyPosts = await db.Post.findAll({
  include: [
    { model: db.Photo, required: false, attributes: [] },
    { model: db.Audio, required: false, attributes: [] },
  ],
  where: [
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('photo.id'), null), 
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('audio.id'), null),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without include

```
db.Post.findAll({
        where: {
            '$photo.id$': { $eq: null },
            '$audio.id$': { $eq: null }
        },
        order: [
            ['createdAt', 'DESC']
        ]
    }).then((posts) => {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: I need those associations in the final instances, though.

Comment: Then why do you have required true, it will not give result if the photos and audios  are empty

Comment: Hm, I see what you're saying, now.  I've actually run into a separate bug in which including a limit breaks the query (bug here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3095)