# Sequelize: How to query for records that don't have association in another table?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have tried many things (like [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11873), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644615/sequelize-where-associated-model-is-null), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62697282/sequelize-find-entries-with-no-association), and ChatGPT solutions) but no success yet.

I have a `users` table, a `userActivities` table and a `userPlans` table, and I need to query for all `users` that have `userActivities` and that do not have any associated record in the `userPlans` table (which is what I couldn't do yet), or that have associations in the `userPlans` table but with the `status` column not equal to `1`.

Basically I need to query for users that has activities but no plan or an inactive plan.

I also need to deal with pagination here.

In the first case of the `switch` I'm getting the users with activities, and here I should also include the ones without plan or with inactive plan.

In the second case of the `switch` I use the table I must use in the first, which is `UserPlans`.

```
    const db = require("../models");

    // ...

    const include = [
      {
        model: db.UserMeta,
        attributes: ["key", "value"],
        where: { del: 0 }
      }
    ];

    if (salesFunnelFilter) {
      switch (salesFunnelFilter) {
        case "qualified":
          include.push({
            model: db.UserActivity,
            required: true,
            attributes: ["type"],
            where: { del: 0, type: saleTriggerActivities }
          });

          // todo: need to filter for users that has no plan or inactive plan here
          break;

        case "premium":
          include.push({
            model: db.UserPlans,
            required: true,
            attributes: ["plan"],
            where: { del: 0, status: 1 }
          });
          break;
      }
    }

    await tUser
      .findAndCountAll({
        where: condition,
        include,
        offset: (pagination.currentPage - 1) * pagination.rowsPerPage,
        limit: pagination.rowsPerPage,
        distinct: true
      })
```

Comment: Basically you need two subqueries in the main `where` using `sequelize.where` and `sequelize.literal`